# Photoshop gradient overlay layer style not visible

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, layer-style, blend-modes

I have been working on Photoshop CS6 for a while now and this is some basic text I did with overlay and a few other settings:

[image]

But now only the normal mode works, but when I put on overlay it just vanishes:

[image]

Comment: Your base color is black? Overlay won't work on a simple black or white fill

Comment: colour is not the issue just tried it in white http://prntscr.com/cc7s0h

Comment: I literally just said it won't work on black or white.  Try it with an actual color.  I'm typing a little more detailed of an explanation as an answer right now.

Comment: I have just tried with red and it still does not work http://prntscr.com/cc7v0w

Comment: @user75259 what are you actually trying to achieve? It sounds like you just need to use a different blending mode... Or just set up your gradient as you want it and use the "normal" blending mode.

Answer (score 1):

`Overlay` isn't doing anything for you, because your base color is black.  `Overlay` needs some color information, other than solid black/white, for its effects to work.

`Overlay` affects the layer beneath it by multiplying and screening at the same time.  This means that areas less than 50% gray will get darkened and areas above 50% will be lightened.

Your problem is that black can't get any darker and white can't get any lighter.

I don't know the science behind it and maybe someone else can chime in with that part of this, but there are certain colors, when fully saturated, that will not be affected by `Overlay`.  See below (poor quality thanks to Zamzar).

[image]

Comment: I tried it with red http://prntscr.com/cc7v0w still not working

Comment: I know it worked with green I will try that now, still not working

Comment: Fully saturated color is like white just in one channel. Each channel is independently evaluated.

Comment: For me it didn't work either. But it worked in a new document. For your information, I can set the text to black or white and the gradient overlay will work normally. It was weird that pressing show preview (to actually turn preview off) would show the effect. It turned out that for me I had to right-click the effects layer and select Show all effects. It was somehow set to hide all effects.